# An alternative to offest = "-1" in Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine

Does anyne know how expression engine deals with a negative offset in a list of channel entries in EE?

as in 
    offset="-1"

Comment: Your question title and question content indicate slightly different questions. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `offset="-1"` in `{exp:channel:entries}`, you'll get a major MySQL error (assuming you're logged in as a super admin or are capable of seeing errors).

It's unclear what your goal is from your question. If you expect a negative offset to reverse the order (like PHP string functions), you can use use the opposite `sort` value. The default is `desc`, so `sort="asc"` would be the reverse. Use a positive `offset="X"` to skip X entries.

If you're expecting an `offset` like in [PHP array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) where you're still going "forward" but a negative offset starts you X entries from the end, I don't believe there's a direct comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The goal was to work with the preceding chanel entry on the same page as the current channel entry.

I managed to do it instead by pulling out the relevant entry_ids and processing them in php and then put them back in with a fixed_order attribute

Comment: Depending on what you need to show, there's also {exp:channel:prev_entry}. That has to be placed outside a channel entries tag but you can get the entry_id and pass it to an embed if you need more than the title, url_title or path variables.